# After change the meta content from EmulateIE7 to Edge, the jQuery dialog box close immediately

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use the jQuery Dialog box on the aspx page. When the button is clicked, the dialog box open. It worked fine on IE7 browser but after I changed the IE7 to Edge, the dialog box show and closed immediately. I searched the web and tried the method for adding `preventDefault` but it didn't doesn't work and has another error.

Here is my code to change IE on aspx page

```
<%--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />--%>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
 <button id="cmdChange" class="btnNarrow" onclick="change();">Change</button>
```

There is jQuery:

```
function change(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();  //Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of   undefined or null reference
    $("#dialogChange").removeClass("hide");
    var dialog = getNewChangeDialog();
    dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Would some one tell me how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added the onclick function on aspx page then call the function inside. Removed the e.preventdefault() in the function change.

The code is aspx page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

       $('#cmdChange').click(function (e) {              
           e.preventDefault();
           change();
       });
 });
```